# Toolbar header Chrome extension persistent across page loads

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get create a Chrome extension that displays a toolbar style header that is docked to the top of the page, pushes all page content down so there is no overlap and will remain persistent across page loads.

The problems I am having are two fold:

1. Keeping it open consistently across page loads similar to the way the
   MozBar extension works. How to do this so that the toolbar is only hidden when a user clicks the extension's icon to hide it again?
2. Best method to ensure ALL content (even other fixed headers) get pushed down cleanly without disrupting any other on page content beyond that injection?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do to create a bar like that, which stays on top of the page even when browsing and loading, is to load the real page inside an `<iframe>`. Although this isn't a good thing to do, since that many sites don't allow being loaded inside a frame (e.g. *google.com*), and you won't be able to browse every dsite. Also it wouldn't be possible to update the address bar of the browser with the current page's address. So, in a nutshell: **you can't** actually do this kind of thing in Chrome. The only **really** permanent thing you can create is a [browser action](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.chrome.com%2Fextensions%2FbrowserAction&ei=H0G5VMDqNpL0asWxgtAM&usg=AFQjCNGQwIgEDiusY1Hkgt4OK8lmsDOJhA&sig2=e-B1J8WrSRpL7A4tlj07jw&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d2s).

Comment: Then why does this work for the MozBar extension? That is something I am trying to figure out. Also, I didn't think it was possible to keep a browser action window open after clicking on the page again. This persistence of the extension UI is something I need to happen, which is the reason I was going for a toolbar embedded in the page itself.